# Google Apps Script - Send Email based on condition in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I only have to send an email automatically if there is a YES or NO condition in a cell. If there is the condition YES send one type of email if NO another type of email

Comment: Ok, so what is the question? Have you already tried something yourself?

Comment: What did you try? Do you have a code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...dt] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  dt.forEach(r => {
    if(r[column number - 1) == 'YES') {
      //send email here
  }
}
```